# How to find if a string contains a substring, no case-sensitivity

Tags: javascript

I want to get if a string contains a given substring, but without case-sensitivity. `.includes()` is case-sensitive - `ABCdef` is not counted as including `abc`. This is expected results for the function I want:

```
func('ABCdef', 'abc') => true
func('AbCdef', 'abc') => true
func('abcdef', 'abc') => true
func('defghi', 'abc') => false
```

How can I make a function like this?

Comment: Make both strings lowercase with `.toLowerCase()`, then do `.includes()`. (both uppercase works too)

Comment: "ABCdef".toLowerCase().includes("abc".toLowerCase())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
function checkIncludes(str, substr){
    return str.toLowerCase().includes(substr.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
check = function(str, substr) {
    return RegExp(substr.replace(/[\\^$.|?*+()[{]/g, '\\$&'), 'i').test(str);
}

check('ABCdef', 'abc'); // true
check('AbCdef', 'abc'); // true
check('abcdef', 'abc'); // true
check('defghi', 'abc') // false
```

Comment: Using RegExp avoids creating a new string using str.toLowerCase() which is useful if str is long